# PHPUnit and die function

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm using phpunit framework and I have a code like this:

```
public function A() {

 try {

   (...some code...)

   die (json_encode ($data));

 }

 catch (Exception $e) {
   die(false);
 }

}
```

This function is called via AJAX and I can't replace die with return. The question is: 
How I can make a unit test with a code like this?

I can't use for this, the asserts.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this question belong to StackOverflow ?

Comment: @slubman, Yes I think it does. I have one vote in to migrated it. If you flag it to be moved it will help get it through faster.

Comment: @doctore: Please don't edit to add back in things that get edited out due to the style guidelines for this site. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some ideas on how to ask questions, but in summary adding thanks in advance in questions is just a distraction from the question; in this community you say thanks by voting and returning the favor by helping others with their questions.

Comment: There's a lot of "I can't" in this question, but not much in the way of explanation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**You can't test that...**

Sometimes unit testing brings up problems like this (untestable situations). That usually means that the problem is not with the testing, but with your code and its architecture.

Here you shouldn't use the `die` function (actually **you shouldn't use `die` to return a HTTP response**), but `echo` the json and then let the script finish properly (or `return` the json and `echo` it somewhere else).

To test this, you can then capture the output and check it (this is a basic example, there is much better I guess).

Conclusion : **the problem is with your code, fix this and then you can try to test it**. If you can't, then no testing.

Comment: +1 You put that better than me. "If it's hard to test, it's badly coded."

Comment: @Blowski : "If it's hard to test, it's badly coded." I love this sentence, this is always a bummer to hear that (i've been in that situation many times), but it's pretty much always true... Good programming is hard ;)

Comment: +1 from me too for give me a new sentence for my signature :D

Comment: while it is a nice rule, sometimes using die() is the difference between 5 minutes of work and 5 days of work.Does it really justify restructuring your app because of one die?

Comment: @MarkKaplun The question is "how to test `die()`", the answer is you can't. **If you want to test this behavior**, you have to use another solution. Else do whatever you want :)

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli I have no problem with the answer that you just can't and it is the end of story, I have objection to the rest of the answer which implies that it is somehow a bad code if you call `die` although for some things like redirection it is exactly what you have to do especially if what you do is in the context of a frameword in which you have limited control of what will happen if you just return instead of die-ing (and because of the answer I tried less to do it, after all it is 4 years old so had to check if anything changed, so tnx for that)

Comment: @MarkKaplun mmmh you are right sorry. I agree with you that the second part of my answer is a little too radical. I didn't take time to re-read and focused on the "is it testable" side.

Answer (score 3):

Why can you not replace `die()` with a `return`?

My solution would be to make this throw an exception, and then catch the exception with another method. Then you can unit test `function a()`, checking that it throws the right kind of exception. The other function handles the `die()`.

Answer (score 3):

actually die seems to be not a good solution here. 
but if there is no way to change this you could probably run the function in another process.

for this you have to write a test file which runs the function A.
ex.

```
<?php
include 'fileWithAFunction.php';
A();
?>
```

now call this script with shell_exec.

```
$return = shell_exec('testscript.php');
```

the return variable holds the output of the testscript.

Comment: +1 for pointing out *how* to do it when you *can't* change the original code for reasons beyond your control.